# Threepenny GUI build fail

Tags: haskell, build, haskell-stack, haskell-snap-framework, threepenny-gui

So I've been trying to install Threepenny GUI for a Haskell college assignment the last few hours without any avail. When stack attemps to build the 'snap-core' dependency, I get the following error:

```
snap-core      > configure
snap-core      > Configuring snap-core-1.0.5.0...
snap-core      > build
snap-core      > Preprocessing library for snap-core-1.0.5.0..
snap-core      > Building library for snap-core-1.0.5.0..
snap-core      > [ 1 of 18] Compiling Snap.Internal.Debug
snap-core      > [ 2 of 18] Compiling Snap.Types.Headers
snap-core      > [ 3 of 18] Compiling Snap.Internal.Http.Types
snap-core      > 
snap-core      > src\Snap\Internal\Http\Types.hs:1285:11: error:
snap-core      >     * Variable not in scope:
snap-core      >         parseTime :: TimeLocale -> t0 -> String -> Maybe UTCTime       
snap-core      >     * Perhaps you meant `parseTimeM' (imported from Data.Time.Format)  
snap-core      >      |
snap-core      > 1285 |     prs = parseTime defaultTimeLocale "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT"
snap-core      >      |           ^^^^^^^^^
Progress 1/4

--  While building package snap-core-1.0.5.0 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\stack\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_3.6.3.0_ghc-9.2.5.exe --verbose=1 --builddir=.stack-work\dist\8a54c84f build --ghc-options " -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I have tried building the dependencies of snap-core with 'stack build --dependencies-only snap-core' with no avail. I've also tried to build the 'time' package on it's own with no avail either. My stack version is up to date also. Any ideas..?

Comment: Is this on Windows? A similar issue has been reported at https://github.com/snapframework/snap-core/issues/326.